# Images not picking up from different density folder in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have kept different density images in 4 different folder. Example. In mipmap-hdpi, mdpi, xdpi, xxdpi, xxxdpi. And I'm using xiomi mi4i phone to test. By checking the density of phone I found out it's xxdpi.

I used `ImagView` to set image. Like

```
android:src="@mipmap/icon"
```

But what I'm finding out is it is taking from mdpi folder. I cleaned rebuilt project also. Nothing is working out. Can somebody please help what could be the problem.

For my verification what I did was I created new test project with only Imageview and kept four different size icons corresponding density folder. But still the image is picked from lower density folder.

Comment: check if you have a typo. all the resources must have the same name.

Comment: Ya all are in same name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line in xml :-

```
android:src="@drawable/icon"
```

Comment: And why should he do that? For good quality answers you should always include a description of the code you're giving the OP - and why this should be used.